# How can I fix this: " cannot convert ‘int**’ to ‘int*’ in initialization"

Tags: pointers

```
using namespace std ; 
void update(int *a,int *b) { 
  int *pa = &a ; int *pb = &b ; *pa = *a + *b ; *pb = *a - *b; 
} 
int main() { 
  int a, b; int *pa = &a, *pb = &b; 
  cin >> a >> b; 
  update(pa,pb) ; 
  cout << a << endl; 
  cout << b << endl ;

}
```

Comment: Solution.cpp: In function ‘void update(int*, int*)’:
Solution.cpp:6:16: error: cannot convert ‘int**’ to ‘int*’ in initialization
    int  *pa = &a ;

Comment: in `update`, `a` is already a pointer, so you shouldn't dereference it again. `int *pa = a`

Comment: Garr Godfrey I have done that Earlier but still it shows same Error

Comment: well, you have the same problem with `b`. I

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are already addresses, so you cannot access to "address of address".

Just remove the ampersands like this:

```
void update(int* a, int* b) {
int* pa = a; int* pb = b; *pa = *a + *b; *pb = *a - *b;
```

}

This ensures you point to an address.